# Use MQTT client pointer amongst C++ functions

Tags: c++, pointers, mqtt, paho

I am using the Paho C++ MQTT library to connect to my broker.

I want my code to be organized the following way :

```
connect();
sendMessage(data);
disconnect();
```

I already managed to connect, send a message and disconnect but only in the same function because of the MQTT client's scope :

```
void sendMessage(){
    // Connect
    mqtt::itoken_ptr conntok = client.connect();
    conntok->wait_for_completion();

    // Sending message
    pubtok = client.publish(topic, char_json, data, qos, false);
    pubtok->wait_for_completion(timeout);

    // Disconnect
    conntok = client.disconnect();
    conntok->wait_for_completion();
}
```

However I want to have those **pieces of code** in three separate functions (to avoid reconnecting/disconnecting every time I send some data)

I guess that I have to use the **mqtt::itoken_ptr conntok** that is returned from the **client.connect()**, but this object has no **get_client()** function, only **mqtt:token** does.

The documentation shows that there is a pointer for the async_client class **std::shared_ptr ptr_t**  but I am unsure how to use it since I'm fairly new to C++. The actual client object is private (under the C++ wrapper).

How can I use the same client object in different functions so I can have the following ?

```
connect(){
   mqtt::itoken_ptr conntok = client.connect();
}
sendMessage(){
   pubtok = client.publish(topic, char_json, data, qos, false);
   pubtok->wait_for_completion(timeout);
}
disconnect(){
   conntok = client.disconnect();
   conntok->wait_for_completion();
}
```

Comment: Here's a more in depth documentation of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Thank you. I read this documentation but couldn't figure out how to retrieve the client.

I cannot return the itoken_ptr (since it's abstract), and cannot return the mqtt:iasync_client either that is returned by

`conntok.get()->get_client();`

Comment: Here's what I tried :

`std::shared_ptr<mqtt::itoken>connectTo(); ` returns a smart_ptr to my main function.

`bool disconnectFrom(std::shared_ptr<mqtt::itoken>token)` uses this token to disconnect by using :

`token->get_client()->disconnect();`

I get no errors during compilation, but get a segmentation fault while trying to disconnect. I assume that's because this token is no longer associated to the client thus the pointer leads nowhere.

Comment: The tokens are associated with the transaction for which they are generated - don't think that's what you want to share. 'client' is what needs sharing. You need somewhere a controller object that creates client and passes it to the sendMessage and disconnect methods.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. However tokens do have a get_client() method which returns the client, but I cannot return the client and then use client.anyMethod() without getting a segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but why can't you in pseudo code:

```
void disconnect(mqtt::iasync_client &client);
void connect(mqtt::iasync_client &client);
void sendMessage(mqtt::iasync_client &client);

controller()
{
   mqtt::async_client client(ADDRESS, CLIENTID);
   connect(client);
   sendMessage(client);
   disconnect(client);
}

connect(&client){
   callback cb;
   client.set_callback(cb); // necessary to avoid segmentation fault
   token = client.connect();
   token->wait_for_completion(timeout);
}

sendMessage(&client){
   callback cb;
   client.set_callback(cb); // necessary to avoid segmentation fault
   pubtok = client.publish(topic, char_json, data, qos, false);
   pubtok->wait_for_completion(timeout);
}

disconnect(&client){
   callback cb;
   client.set_callback(cb);
   conntok = client.disconnect();
   conntok->wait_for_completion();
}
```

Comment: Your post made me realize I wasn't passing the client properly as a parameter. I used your pseudo-code and it now works. I had to pass client by reference, like the following : `connectTo(mqtt::iasync_client& client)`.

Comment: To be honest I'm still not 100% happy with this solution ; this my data is sent in a loop from a **main.cpp** file, the solution above forces me to declare and initialize my **async_client** in the same file (in the same function, even). I wish I could have a global instance of client stored in another file !